# Scheduling - uniprogramming VS multiprogramming example

Tags: architecture, system, scheduling

There are three independent jobs (i.e., they are not constrained by
dependencies on each other and they have different I/O needs).

They need 20 s, 30 s and 40 s CPU time, respectively, and during their
executions each of them spends one minute waiting for I/O.

Compute the optimal (i.e., minimal) overall runtime of these jobs when they are
processed

a. in a uniprogrammed system
b. in a multiprogrammed system

#### For the uniprogrammed system

I know that only one process can be loaded in the main memory at once, so only after the first job is completed the second can begin and enter. So for the first job i have the 20s processing time and added it to the 60s for i/o which has given me 80s.

For the second job I have done the same so have got 30 + 60 = 90; again the same for the final third and got 30 + 60 = 90.

Does anyone know if I done this the right way considering it is a uniprogramming system. I couldn't think of any other way.

#### For the multiprogrammed system

I have looked at using the FIFO method; here is my calculation:

```
+----+--------------+
| p  |  burst time  |
+----+--------------+
| p1 |           20 |
| p2 |           30 |
| p3 |           40 |
+----+--------------+
```

```
   p1  p2  p3

0  20  30  40
```

turnaround
20+ 30+40 = 90/3 = 30

wait time
0+20+30 = 50/31 = 16.6

Not sure if anyone can help me out here to understand this and where I may be going wrong.

Comment: If the jobs run sequentially, the time will add up, and so you are right there that it'd be ((60 + 20) + (60 + 30) + (60 + 40)). If the jobs run in parallel and if they can truly run in a manner that none has to wait for any other job (even during I/O), then the time will simply be the maximum of the three times which is (60 + 40).

Answer (score 0):

For uniprogrammed uniprocessor it is ((60 + 20) + (60 + 30) + (60 + 40))
and for multiprogrammed uniprocessor system it is 60+40+30+20